# Python - Django - Form fields not showing on HTML page

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms, csrf

I am learning Django and am trying to set up a simple form HTML with form fields which I can send via POST method.
However, if I load HTML page the fields are not visible

The HTML page is create.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Create a task
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create a task</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}
        {{ form.task }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        <span>{{ error }}</span>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control"><br>
      <textarea placeholder="Enter description" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
```

My forms.py file is as follows:

```
from .models import Task
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea


class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["title", "task"]
        widgets = {
            "title": TextInput(attrs={
                        'class': 'form-control',
                        'placeholder': 'Enter name'
                    }),
                    "task": Textarea(attrs={
                        'class': 'form-control',
                        'placeholder': 'Enter description'
                    }),
        }
```

and views.py is as this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Task
from .forms import TaskForm

def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'title': 'Main page of this website', 'tasks': tasks})


def about(request):
    return render(request, "main/about.html")


def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            redirect('home')
        else:
            error = 'The form has incorrect values'

    form = TaskForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    return render(request, "main/create.html")
```

It appears to me that

```
        {{ form.title }}
```

and

```
        {{ form.task }}
```

are not working properly. However, I do not know how to adjust the code to make them visible. I browsed similar questions and suspect it's because GET request is not defined in view, but I do not know how to fix it.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: `return render(request, "main/create.html")` In the create view, you're not passing the context into the render call.  So `form` ends up being an undefined/blank variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you! Completely missed it!

Answer (score 2):

@John Gordon helped in comments, I was not passing the context into the render call

```
    return render(request, "main/create.html", context)
```

fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Like @filidoublep states, you need to return the `context` as well. To do this with a class based FormView you can do the following:

```py
class NewFormView(FormView):
    form_class = NewForm
    fields = ["field1", "field2", ]
    template = "app/template.html"

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        
        # Add additional logic, maybe htmx or something else.
        
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```